# How can rollup plugins generate its .d.ts types with .js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollup, lib

As title, how can rollup plugins generate its `.d.ts` types with `.js` file without `jsdoc`.

for example,  I can't find `jsdoc` and `.ts` file in `rollup-plugin-commonjs` (https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs),
but this package has its `.d.ts` declaration.

rollup-plugin-commonjs [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.d.ts` files don't need to be automatically generated from JSDoc or `.ts` files, they can be manually written.

It looks like the authors of this plugin decided to write the `.d.ts` file themselves and use vanilla JS for the actual code.

Comment: rollup official plugins （https://github.com/rollup/plugins） are  all like this... i can't image... thanks ~